# How to get Map data using JDBCTemplate.queryForMap

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

How to load data from `JDBCTemplate.queryForMap()` as it returns the Map Interface? How is the query data maintained internally in the map? I tried to load it, but I got this exception:  **org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result**

Code:-

```
public List getUserInfoByAlll() {
    List profilelist=new ArrayList();
    Map m=new HashMap();
    m=this.jdbctemplate.queryForMap("SELECT userid,username  FROM USER");
    Set s=m.keySet();
    Iterator it=s.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        String its=(String)it.next();
        Object ob=(Object)m.get(its);
        log.info("UserDAOImpl::getUserListSize()"+ob);
    }
    return profilelist;
}
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`queryForMap` is appropriate if you want to get a single row.  You are selecting without a `where` clause, so you probably want to `queryForList`.  The error is probably indicative of the fact that `queryForMap` wants one row, but you query is retrieving many rows.

[Check out the docs.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/)  There is a `queryForList` that takes just sql; the return type is  a

`List<Map<String,Object>>`.

So once you have the results, you can do what you are doing.  I would do something like

```
List results = template.queryForList(sql);

for (Map m : results){
   m.get('userid');
   m.get('username');
}
```

I'll let you fill in the details, but I would not iterate over keys in this case.  I like to explicit about what I am expecting.

If you have a `User` object, and you actually want to load User instances, you can use the `queryForList` that takes sql and a class type

`queryForList(String sql, Class<T> elementType)`

(wow Spring has changed a lot since I left Javaland.)

Comment: We are having queryForObject if retriving single object.what is difference between queryForObject and queryForMap?

Comment: from the documentation, queryForObject returns an instance of the specified class.  queryForMap returns a map where each column is a key for the value.

Answer (score 55):

I know this is really old, but this is the simplest way to query for Map.

Simply implement the ResultSetExtractor interface to define what type you want to return. Below is an example of how to use this. You'll be mapping it manually, but for a simple map, it should be straightforward.

```
jdbcTemplate.query("select string1,string2 from table where x=1", new ResultSetExtractor<Map>(){
    @Override
    public Map extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,DataAccessException {
        HashMap<String,String> mapRet= new HashMap<String,String>();
        while(rs.next()){
            mapRet.put(rs.getString("string1"),rs.getString("string2"));
        }
        return mapRet;
    }
});
```

This will give you a return type of Map that has multiple rows (however many your query returned) and not a list of Maps. You can view the ResultSetExtractor docs here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html

Comment: I prefer this answer to the chosen one, much simpler, less work required.

Comment: @mohammedkhan Not to mention less temporary objects alocated

Answer (score 34):

To add to @BrianBeech's answer, this is even more trimmed down in java 8:

```
jdbcTemplate.query("select string1,string2 from table where x=1", (ResultSet rs) -> {
    HashMap<String,String> results = new HashMap<>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        results.put(rs.getString("string1"), rs.getString("string2"));
    }
    return results;
});
```

Comment: HashMap<String,String> results = new HashMap<>();
        results.put(rs.getString("string1"), rs.getString("string2"));
    return results;

Comment: No need for while loop , already it is getting itrated over resultset

Answer (score 11):

You can do something like this.

```
 List<Map<String, Object>> mapList = jdbctemplate.queryForList(query));
    return mapList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> (Long) k.get("userid"), k -> (String) k.get("username")));
```

Output:

```
 {
  1: "abc",
  2: "def",
  3: "ghi"
}
```