# Spring JDBC obtaining a list of maps

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

probably something super simple. I'd like to retrieve two sets of key (String) and value(double) from a simple query which returns one row with two columns.

There must be a cleaner way to do it than what I have below - that's 10 lines to get the job done, which seems overkill. Any recommendation what to use instead? Thanks!

```
List<Map<String, Double>> RecordList = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(Queries.GET_DATASET(),
                getParsedQuery(request), resultSet -> {
                    List<Map<String, Double>> list = new ArrayList();
                    HashMap mMap = new HashMap();
                    mMap.put("this_year", resultSet.getDouble("this_year"));
                    list.add(mMap);
                    mMap = new HashMap();
                    mMap.put("last_year", resultSet.getDouble("last_year"));
                    list.add(mMap);
                    return list;
                });
```

Comment: Have you considered the `queryForMap()` method?

Comment: `queryForList` returns almost what you want (a `List<Map<String,Object>>`). [Have a look for more options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029785/how-to-get-map-data-using-jdbctemplate-queryformap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a MutablePair from Apache Commons. You can find javadoc [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/MutablePair.html):

With that approach you could keep `this_year` in the **L**, and `last_year` on **R**. L meaning left object and R right object.

You could replace the code with something like that:

```
return MutablePair.of(resultSet.getDouble("this_year"),resultSet.getDouble("last_year")));
```

If you prefer not to use the Apache Commons, have a look at some [alternatives](https://www.techiedelight.com/five-alternatives-pair-class-java/):